# Disable Firefox content blocking/shield animation

Tags: firefox

Is it possible to disable this animation on Firefox without disabling the content blocking feature altogether?

[image: animation]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no 'native' way to disable **just** this specific animation, but you can disable it via disabling all animations, in the following manner:

1. In the address bar, go to `about:config`.
2. Search for `toolkit.cosmeticAnimations.enabled`. It should have its value set to `true`.
3. Right click on this option's line, and choose **Toggle**, so its value is now false.

An example of another animation that this will effect is the quick 'progress bar' of a tab in the tabs bar when refreshing a page:

[image: firefox tab refresh animation]

Comment: The animation in your gif is actually still active after toggling that setting (on Windows 10). Thanks.

Comment: Interesting. On my Ubuntu 18.04.2 it becomes disabled.